# A página da fila de análise não é renderizada completamente

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

Parece ser um problema meu ou do Firefox já que o mesmo aconteceu ao seguir um link não relacionado com o stackoverflow.

---

Por vezes, ao clicar no texto/link Analisar (Ferramentas|Analisar) da página da fila de análise, a página não é renderizada completamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O mesmo aconteceu ao fazer *refresh* da página de perguntas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso o Firefox <s>57.0.2</s> 57.0.3

Comment: Isso nunca me aconteceu. Uso o Chrome atualizado.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque o problema não é relacionado com o Stackoverflow.

Comment: O problema foi um Add-on, ou ISP ou versão do FF?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Não sei. O problema continua. A diferença é que aconteceu também numa página não relacionada com o Stackoverflow. Os Add-on e ISP são os mesmos de antes. Não consigo fazer relação com à versão do FF. A única coisa que alterei foi o anti vírus(Bitdefender) mas não posso assegurar que o problema tenha surgido apenas depois.

Comment: bug em um add-on que ocasionou devido a um update do Firefox provavelmente, se olhar o "inspetor de elementos" e o console provavelmente irá notar algum erro.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Vou ver quando voltar a acontecer. O que já fiz foi "Ver fonte da página" e, aparentemente, não vi nada diferente de quando ela é renderizada.

Comment: Código fonte não exibe o tempo de execução do DOM renderizado, os add-ons geralmente manipulam via JS e não via requisição HTTP. Se for um BUG ocorre no tempo de execução, clique com o inspetor de elemento quando o erro ocorrer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Obrigado. Clico onde? Em qualquer parte branca da tela? Note que eu sou leigo(praticamente) no que se refere a esses assuntos :(

Comment: clica em qualquer lugar com o direito e selecione insepect element (depende do idioma do navegador) e vai aparecer o DOM gerado, então vai até o elemento HTML e clique com o direito do rato no elemento `<html>` mesmo, selecione Copy e depois `Copy outerHTML`, o conteudo talvez nos fornecerá um "um norte" para que possamos detectar a falha.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Não dá para colocar na pergunta, são cerca de 55800 caracteres.

Comment: @ramaral coloca no http://pastebin.com e coloca o link que deu o problema (de onde copiou o DOM gerado)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KWZ8rGW2). Link da página com problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review.

Comment: @ramaral pelo source do DOM gerado, tudo que veio após o elemento `</header>` foi removido dinamicamente mesmo, não parece ser erro de parse do HTML (motor de renderização), porque se fosse teria resquícios do resto da pagina, mas não encontrei sinal algum, então é bem provavel que seja mesmo um scritp via GreaseMonkey e TamperMonkey ou add-on, e provavelmente um deles conflita com as ultimas atualizações do FF.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Obrigado pela ajuda. Vou verificar os *add-on*. Talvez o **Adblock**?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. O estranho é que não acontece sempre e se eu fizer refresh a página renderiza.

Comment: Pode sim ser o Adblock, pode ser conflito com o WinterBash e Adblock também. Qual adblock vc usa? Aliais quais extensões vc usa?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP.Eyeo Adblock Plus 3.0.2, EPUBReader 2.0.5, Greasemonkey 4.1 com o script *stackexchange-tab-editing*.

Comment: @ramaral tentei tudo que pude aqui e realmente não consegui o efeito, tente desativar um add-on por vez, mas se não der certo talvez seja um daqueles casos de fazer backup das senhas e favoritos e reinstalar o navegador.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Já fiz isso. Desactivei o Addblock e o Greasemonkey, um de cada vez, mas o problema manifestou-se igual.

Comment: @ramaral se tem certeza que desativou "todos" add-ons e ainda sim o problema persiste o que sugiro é você experimentar criar uma nova instalação do zero paralela, pois é muito estranho mesmo o DOM ser manipulado desta forma.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. Se os add-ons são as "Extensões", sim, desactivei um de cada vez e em cada uma das vezes problema manifestou-se. Será do antivírus? Eu mudei de antivírus mais ou menos na altura em que o problema surgiu. A mudança ocorreu 2 dias antes de ter feito a pergunta. No entanto, a pergunta não foi feita no dia em que, pela primeira vez, surgiu o problema. Por isso não consigo saber se o problema existia antes da mudança do antivírus.

Comment: @ramaral se fizer uma instalação paralela (sem add-ons) e ocorrer o mesmo então poderemos presumir que é um BUG do Firefox no seu sistema operacional.

Comment: @ramaral Solução final pros seus problemas: use o Chrome. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Julgo que posso afirmar que o problema se devia ao Bitdefender. Desde que o desinstalei, faz uma semana, o problema não mais se manifestou.

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar esta informação, apesar de ser off isso pode ajudar muitas pessoas com condições semelhantes em suas máquinas.